# Django save method is not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-3.0

I overrode Django save method. On saving new Discount item, print statements are executed but update_discount method is not called. I'm using Admin panel to save Discount items. I want to call same update_discount method on Django update method too.

CODE:

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(default=now)
    end_date = models.DateField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    disc_per = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('start_date', 'end_date', 'product')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.start_date) + '-' + str(self.end_date) + '-' + str(self.product)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('saved.')
        Discount.update_discount()
        print('updated discount.')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def update_discount():
        discounts = Discount.get_all_discounts()
        products = Product.get_all_products()
        today = date.today()

        # Reset discounted prices of all products
        products.update(disc_price=None)

        # Apply discount on products if today is sale
        for discount in discounts:
            product = Product.get_product_by_id(discount.product.id)

            if (today >= discount.start_date) and (today <= discount.end_date):
                per = discount.disc_per
                price = discount.product.price

                disc_price = Discount.cal_disc_price(per, price)
                product.update(disc_price=disc_price)
            else:
                product.update(disc_price=None)
```

OUTPUT:

```
saved.
updated discount.
```

Comment: try using self.  **self.update_discount()**

Comment: @c.grey I earlier tried self.update_discount() . It didn't work.

Comment: Try to print something in the **update_discount** function.

Comment: A lot of static methods are called but implementations are not shared. It is hard to say what is wrong

Comment: Why did you know that the `update_discount` method is not called?

Comment: @ruddra It's so weird! Can you show the sample code about this `A lot of static methods are called but implementations are not shared`?

Comment: I realised I was calling update_discount method before saving Discount item. As a result, newly added discount method was not applied. Thank you everyone for your kind help.

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that why did you know that the `update_discount` method is not called. But you should try to fix it like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    print('saved.')
    self.update_discount()
    print('updated discount.')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my silly mistake. I didn't know that we can add code after super().save(*args, **kwargs).